# Approximate SIVP worst-case hardness: proper mathematical formulation used for cryptographic purposes

Tags: lattice-crypto

Is the following a correct formulation for the assumed worst-case hardness of $SIVP_\gamma$?

- For every PPT algorithm $A$
- for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists a basis $B_{n,A}=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\} \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ such that
- Pr[A produces an answer for $SIVP_\gamma$ on $B_{n,A}$]$\to 0$
  faster than any 1/poly(n).

Specifically, is that what one assumes when proving that Ajtai's family of functions is a one-way family of functions?